# Python Paramiko Router passing/storing variables SSH other routers

Tags: python, variables, ssh, router, paramiko

I have been reading over the threads here, and can't seem to find what I am looking for. I will start this off by saying I am a new @ using Python, but taking a few classes. 
The goal is to be able to SSH into a Router, run a command (script below does this)
Next is to be able to grep or extract info from the command, and store this as a variable. 
The example would be to track down a route, the router will display a prefix, and the next hop. I would like the script to be able to store the next hop in a variable, and then exit out of the router, and SSH into the variable stored.

The basic question is how would I go about writing this into a python script?

Below is the code I have that works so far:

```
import paramiko
import time


def disable_paging(remote_conn):
     "Disable Screen Length 24"

 remote_conn.send("environment no more\n")
 time.sleep(1)
ip = '192.168.0.1'
name = 'ROUTER1' #PUT ROUTER NAME HERE IF YOU WANT
username = 'LOGMEIN' # PUT YOUR USERNAME HERE
password = 'PASSWORD' # PUT YOUR PASSWORD HERE

remote_conn_pre = paramiko.SSHClient()
remote_conn_pre

remote_conn_pre.set_missing_host_key_policy(
paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())

remote_conn_pre.connect(ip, username = username, password = password,
look_for_keys = False, allow_agent = False)

print "SSH connection established to %s" % name


remote_conn = remote_conn_pre.invoke_shell()
print "SSH session established to %s, %s"  %(ip, name)
# Strip the initial router prompt
output = remote_conn.recv(1000)
print output

 # DEFINE COMMANDS HERE:
remote_conn.send("environment no more\n") # removes the break after 24 lines,      no needed to press a key
remote_conn.send("show router route-table 0.0.0.0\n")

    # Wait for the command to complete
time.sleep(2)

    # this is the buffer for # of lines to receive? 5000?
output = remote_conn.recv(5000)
print output
```

Comment: Can you add a sample 'prefix'?

Comment: the script will be futher modified by permitting the user to enter an IP that will be tracked down.

Comment: I need to be able to parse and store the next-hop from the output of the command for instance route-table lookup of 10.24.0.5 would result in next-hop 10.10.10.1, the next hop (10.10.10.1) needs to then be stored, and then repeat the same steps of SSH into 10.10.10.1